# "this" return undefined in a prototype function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, prototype

I want to run multiples asynchronous task with async package.
But I have issues with javascript prototypes access.

Here's the sample of my code:

```js
var env = function(options) {
    this.options = options;
}

env.prototype.run = function() {
  
  var self = this,
  async.series([
    self.task1,
    self.task2
  ], function done(responses) {
      console.log(responses);
  });
}


env.prototype.task1 = function() {
  console.log(this.options); // undefined
  // logic code...
}



var foo = new env({foo: 'bar'});
foo.run(); // undefined - from console.log
```

**Don't know why I can't access the 'this' properties of my Object**

Comment: Press th`Run code snippet` button and see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

Comment: Stack Snippets are for **runnable** examples, but the above isn't runnable. A runnable example is very useful, because it ensures that you haven't left out important information and that people can see the problem. It also makes it easy for people to show you a working fix. If you're not going to make it runnable, just use a code block (the `{}` toolbar button), but I do encourage you to keep using snippets -- just make them runnable.

Comment: Just realized that while the presentation is a bit different from the usual, at heart this is a duplicate of the question I just linked. Hopefully this question will help others who use `async.series` who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
async.series([
  self.task1,
  self.task2
], function done(responses) {
    console.log(responses);
});
```

just passes function references into `async.series`, but does nothing to ensure that `this` is correct when they're called.

Unless the `async.series` you're using offers a way to tell it what `this` to use, you can readily solve the problem with `bind`:

```
async.series([
  self.task1.bind(self),        // ***
  self.task2.bind(self)         // ***
], function done(responses) {
    console.log(responses);
});
```

Here's a simpler example demonstrating the problem and solution:

```js
var obj = {
  property: "testing",
  wrong: function() {
    setTimeout(this.task1, 10);
  },
  right: function() {
    setTimeout(this.task1.bind(this), 20);
  },
  task1: function() {
    console.log("task1 says the property is " + this.property);
  }
};

obj.wrong();
obj.right();
```

---

Side note: Unless you're using `self` for something you haven't shown inside `run`, you don't need it at all:

```
env.prototype.run = function() {
  async.series([
    this.task1.bind(this),
    this.task2.bind(this)
  ], function done(responses) {
      console.log(responses);
  });
};
```

Another option if you're using an ES2015-compatible environment (or transpiling) is to wrap your tasks in arrow functions:

```
// Requres ES2015 support
env.prototype.run = function() {
  async.series([
    (...args) => this.task1(...args),
    (...args) => this.task2(...args)
  ], function done(responses) {
      console.log(responses);
  });
};
```

Comment: But in this sample code I saw that **this** refers to the right **task1** function because I got an output message from my console.log()

Comment: @SimonBruneaud: Yes, the right *function*. But the function is *called* with the wrong value for `this`.

Comment: But the bind make the console.log work, thanks.
I'll read a bit more about this **Bind** function

Comment: @SimonBruneaud the key thing to understand is that the value of `this` depends on how a function is **called**, not on how the function is declared.